# Check if a string contains a list of substrings and save the matching ones

Tags: c#, string, contains

This is my situation: I have a string representing a text

```
string myText = "Text to analyze for words, bar, foo";
```

And a list of words to search for in it

```
List<string> words = new List<string> {"foo", "bar", "xyz"};
```

I'd want to know the most efficient method, if exists, to get the list of the words contained in the text, something like that:

```
List<string> matches = myText.findWords(words)
```

Comment: Efficient in terms of CPU time or memory?

Comment: What would be the size of `myText` and how many search operations will you be doing/

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "word".  Should "foo" be matched in a string like "This is foobar"?  The `Contains` answers would match that, while the `Split` answers would not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no special analysis in this query except you have to use `Contains` method. So you may try this:

```
string myText = "Text to analyze for words, bar, foo";

List<string> words = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "xyz" };

var result = words.Where(i => myText.Contains(i)).ToList();
//result: bar, foo
```

Comment: This is probably the best option, factoring in efficiency of coding time (which should not be ignored)

Comment: @DrewKennedy as far as the problem is not complicated, why not go for most simple and compact solution

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad I agree that it doesn't matter. I think the comment refers to this method requiring multiple passes over the string, which is not necessary. Furthermore, there is the Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm that could significantly speed up the algorithm if the words are relatively long.

Comment: @Bas Thanks. I'm going to check the *Boyer-Moore-Horspool* algorithm

Comment: Should be noted that this would match "foo" in a string like "This is foobar", which may or may not be the desired result.

Comment: @juharr Yes. This is the general idea. If he don't like those result so he can do it like this `myText.Contains(" "+i+" "))`

Comment: @HosseinNamariRad What about 'This is foo. This is foo?'. Maybe a Regex `\b` would help in that department.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `HashSet<string>` and intersect both collections:

```
string myText = "Text to analyze for words, bar, foo"; 
string[] splitWords = myText.Split(' ', ',');

HashSet<string> hashWords = new HashSet<string>(splitWords,
                                                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
HashSet<string> words = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "foo", "bar" },
                                            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

hashWords.IntersectWith(words);
```

Comment: While this handles the given example it wouldn't work with a string like "Here is foo! Where is bar? I am xyz.".  Basically you'd need to split on anything that can separate words.  Also the OP did not mention if "foo" should be matched in a string like "This is foobar".

Comment: @juharr This is an example of what the OP can do with a `HashSet`. He can split on any separator he wants. He may also trim the strings before inserting them into the collection, which I haven't done.

Comment: I totally agree that this is the way to go if the OP wants to look at words and not just any sub-string.  I just thought it should be pointed out that the splitting process might be more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

A Regex solution

```
var words = new string[]{"Lucy", "play", "soccer"};
var text = "Lucy loves going to the field and play soccer with her friend";
var match = new Regex(String.Join("|",words)).Match(text);
var result = new List<string>();

while (match.Success) {
    result.Add(match.Value);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}

//Result ["Lucy", "play", "soccer"]
```

Comment: You should use Regex.Escape

Answer (score 0):

Playing off of the idea that you want to be able to use `myText.findWords(words)`, you can make an extension method to the String class to do just what you want.

```
public static class StringExtentions
{
    public static List<string> findWords(this string str, List<string> words)
    {
        return words.Where(str.Contains).ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string myText = "Text to analyze for words, bar, foo";
List<string> words = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "xyz" };
List<string> matches = myText.findWords(words);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", matches.ToArray()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Results:

> foo, bar

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that accounts for whitespace and punctuation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sentence = "Text to analyze for words, bar, foo";            
    var words = Regex.Split(sentence, @"\W+");
    var searchWords = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "xyz" };
    var foundWords = words.Intersect(searchWords);

    foreach (var item in foundWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```